# Child shell does not get empty environment variables and arrays of parent shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vagrant, sh

After installation of Ruby Version Manager (RVM) as root on an Ubuntu 14.04. I am confronted with a strange behaviour of bash. Let's have a look at the exported environment variables. I login as user ubunutu and run `export`in my bash. Here are three of rvm's exported environment variables, others are available:

```
declare -ax chpwd_functions='([0]="__rvm_cd_functions_set" [1]="__rvm_after_cd")'
declare -x rvm_version="1.25.28 (stable)"
declare -x rvm_ruby_mode
```

Everything is pretty fine, but when I run `bash -c export` we get only:

```
declare -x rvm_version="1.25.28 (stable)"
```

Can someone explain me why all empty environment variables and all arrays are removed in the child bash? What must I do to ensure that really all environment variables of a parent shell are available within a child shell?

This problem is really a blocker for me. I am using vagrant and its shell provisioner. In one script I setup rvm and in a second one I must configure some gemsets. The problem is that in the second script the rvm commands do not run. The active shell only gets those environment variables of rvm with are non-arrays and non-empty. Manually sourcing of `rvm.sh` is no solution!

Answer (score 2):

It is because as per last line of `man bash`:

> Array variables may not (yet) be exported.

I read somewhere a note by BASH developer that it is because exporting an array is very complex and error prone.

Also this line:

```
declare -x rvm_ruby_mode
```

is only declaring a name of the variable with export attribute set (without value), if you assign it a value it will be available in the sub shell.

**[Here is post by BASH author on export of array in BASH.](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But isn't it an inconsequent behaviour of the shell. As you can see the array is correctly exported, so arrays are supported in general. But only in the case of a subshell all arrays become removed indicating that they are unsupported.

Comment: `declare -ax chpwd_functions` is merely declaring an array but when sub shell is forked BASH exports all the variables **except** array variables.

Comment: [Read this post by BASH author](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html) about exporting array variables.

Comment: Techinically, `rvm_ruby_mode` isn't even an empty variable, just a name with the export attribute set.

Comment: Yes that is right, `declare -x rvm_ruby_mode` declares a variable but merely declares a name of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

A variable is created when a value is assigned to a name using the `=` operator, for example

```
foo=bar
```

creates a variable named `foo` with the value `bar`.

`declare` is used for two reasons: one, to allow dynamic creation of variables (which is beyond the scope of this question), and two, to set attributes on *names* (not necessarily variables). The command

```
declare -x rvm_ruby_mode
```

simply sets the export attribute of the *name* `rvm_ruby_mode`. To actually create a variable whose name has the export attribute set, you need to use the `=` operator, just as without the `declare` command.

```
declare -x rvm_ruby_mode=
```

*Now* `rvm_ruby_mode` is an empty variable whose named is marked for export.

I say "marked for export" because variables are not exported until a subshell is created. Until then, there is simply a list of names that, if the name has a value when a subshell/child process is created, are copied into the new environment. This list is separate from the list of actual variables (which again are names with associated values).

As to why arrays cannot be exported? The environment is technically not a set of variables, since a variable is a shell construct and the environment is something used by *all* processes in POSIX, whether or not run by a shell. The environment is simply a list of strings of the form `<name>=<value>`. There is no standard for how to pack the elements of an array into a single string which any process can parse and reconstruct into an appropriate data structure. While it's possible that `bash` could make an exception if it new the child process was another `bash` shell and come up with some way of embedding an array in the environment (like it does with function definitions), apparently this has not been done.

Comment: Thanky you very much! That's help a lot. So the variable  `rvm_ruby_mode` is only declared but not defined yet. It becomes defined if a value is assigned and bash only exports defined and non-array variables, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say that `rvm_ruby_mode` is declared (`bash` doesn't have variable declarations); it simply marks an attribute on a *name* without defining a variable by that name. But terminology aside, your understanding is correct.